# How to make an onclick function submit a form and do it's action?

Tags: javascript, html

My plan is to have a division that has an onclick event that will pass a form. Note that the division is not part of the form, instead, I want to make an onclick function that would execute the form action and put it on a target (which is an iframe, by the way). My code goes like this:

```
<style>
    #myiframe {
    position: absolute; 
    display:none; }
</style>
<script>
    function myFunctionExecuteForm()
    {
        //(execute the action of the form here)
    }
</script>
<iframe id="myframe" name="carsearch" scrolling="no" frameborder = "0" style = "position:absolute;top:42px; left:287px; width:723px; height:528px;"></iframe>

<div onclick="myFunctionExecuteForm()">Save</div> //The division

<form name="search" id="search" method="get" action="/crime_map/map_crime.php" target="carsearch">
</form>
```

Thanks for your help! :D

Answer (score 1):

Do it using

`document.forms["search"].submit();`

Answer (score 0):

use jquery on click function like following code

```
jQuery('id/class of submitbutton').on('click',function(){
----your code here ------
}
```

or use this html

```
   <form name="search"  onsubmit="return function_name();" id="search" method="get" action="/crime_map/map_crime.php" target="carsearch">
```

Answer (score 0):

I would give the div an id or class, but below should work

```
$( "div" ).click(function() {
   $( "#search" ).submit();
});
```